# Rate Distortion Optimized Quantization

Tags: algorithm, optimization, hevc

Hi i am working on HEVC standard using HM Reference code Version 10.0. Basically i am planning to RD Optimized Quantization. Theoritically we need to Minimize the Cost Function J=D+Lambda*R. My question is How we have to Estimate R before Entropy Encoding for a Particular Frame. Also Which algorithm is used for RDOQ in HM code. Please provide me help as which are the functions that are doing RD Optimization in HM code. I am unable to follow the code flow. I will be happy if you provide me any links that explains code flow in HM Ref code. Thanks..

Comment: Will this document help? http://phenix.it-sudparis.eu/jct/doc_end_user/current_document.php?id=2858

Comment: Hi Fredrik, i would like to know what exactly the function clip3() does?

Comment: That function is defined in `source/Lib/TLibCommon/CommonDef.h` and used like `Clip3(min, max, a)` the usage is to clip **a**, such that `minVal <= a <= maxVal`.

Comment: Hi Fredrik could you please answer questions i posed below..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long to put in a comment...

First, why 10.0?

Anyway, search for the definition

```
#if ADAPTIVE_QP_SELECTION
```

in the code-base

Have a look at the function `Void TComTrQuant::xRateDistOptQuant` in file

```
source/Lib/TLibCommon/TComTrQuant.cpp
```

Hope it helps...

Comment: Could this really be too long to put in a comment...?

First, why 10.0?

Anyway, search for the definition

`#if ADAPTIVE_QP_SELECTION`
in the code-base

Have a look at the function `Void TComTrQuant::xRateDistOptQuant` in file

`source/Lib/TLibCommon/TComTrQuant.cpp`
Hope it helps...

Comment: @clwhisk -- does it matter? The question doesn't have an definitive answer and usually it ends up as a discussion, hence the "answer" and the ability to have a structured discussion...

Comment: There are many inane reasons people here might call out a post like this, factual inaccuracy is mine.

Comment: My Query is how to allocate Target Bit Rate for each Coding Units before Actual CABAC Encoding is done. I read that we need to Estimate the Rate, but i dont know on what Basis we have to Estimate the Rate.

Comment: Basically i am looking into the function xRateDistOptQuant in TComTrQuant.cpp. I need to experiment How will be the Quality of the video for Chroma Components if we enable RDOQ and by Disabling TEXT_LUMA directive. Could anyone please give me any inputs...i am unable to follow algorithm implemented in xRateDistOptQuant.

Comment: After some Literature What i Understood is For each Transform Coefficient we need to set some Predefined levels and calculate the cost by finding Distortion and thereby rate using the Equation J=D+\lambda R . My question is how to get lambda and do we have to choose different set of levels for each Transform Coefficient?